# android explaination addview & layoutparams during runtime

Tags: android, imageview, layoutparams

just want to know what happens when I set new layout params to a new instance of an ImageView and then add it on an empty layout. It seems like doing it reset the parent layout hosting the new ImageView and also reset position and size of every sibling ImageView.

So what happens? Parent layout takes the layoutparams of the child?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout params have **direct affect** to views which use that params. But that also affects other views under same parent. Think about width, height and weight attrs of linear layout params. For example, if you set a layout params which has a weight attr defined, this will all change the visual of your parent.

[From the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html):

> LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to
>   be laid out.

**Note:** 
A parent is a view group, a container for child views. There are some types of view groups, ie `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc(subclasses of `ViewGroup` can be googled), and they have specific layout behaviours and `LayoutParams`. While adding views to view groups layout params are used (both on xml and programmatically) for setting position, width, height inside that view group(container).

Comment: So basically I can't add a view without affecting previously added ones. right? You said that the params affect the other views too.

Comment: It depends on your parent and your params. Consider having only one parent and some child views inside it.

Comment: that's exactly what I have, but every time I add a child all the previously added children are set at the same position and size...

Comment: Then that's another question I think. It depends on what do you have for parent? A linear, frame, relative? what kind of param do you use? Just post your code/xml in another question.